# Check if an array of radio boxes is selected

Tags: jquery

I have built a booking form, Where users can select the number of bikes for a booking.

What I need to do is, Then make sure that the user is selecting that radio button.

In any case, You can have up to 10 bikes to select from.

What I would like to do is a for loop to get the number of bikes and then make sure each radio button is selected, If that is the case then submit the form.

I have managed to achieve this so far, For 1 bike. But how do I achieve this for a higher number of bikes?

My jQuery code is as follows :

```
        $('.booking-button').click(function()
    {
        var number_of_bikes = $('.bike-number').val();

        for(i = 0; i < number_of_bikes; i++)
        {
            var packages = $("input[name='bikes[]"+i"]").is(':checked');

            if(packages == false)
            {
                alert("Please select a bike package");
            }
            else
            {
                // Submit The Form
                $('.booking-form').submit();
            }
        }
        return false;
    })
```

Within that for loop, I would ideally like to add 1,2,3,4 etc.

To create HTML like so :

```
<input type="radio" title="69" value="package1" name="bikes[]1" class="radio-price bike1">
<input type="radio" title="69" value="package1" name="bikes[]2" class="radio-price bike2">
```

How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var packages_len = $("input[name^='bikes[]']:checked").length; //length of all checked radio buttons 
if (packages_len < number_of_bikes) {
    alert("Please select bike packages");
}
```

[Attribute Starts With Selector [name^="value"]](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

Comment: Hi, I've ran this through my system and packages_len keeps returning "0"? *EDIT* This has now worked with your modified code. Many Thanks!